# Read key from java console exception

Tags: java, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I want to read a key from console but I get this exception and I am pretty stacked on it. I would appreciated any help!

```
public char readKey() {
        char key = ' ';
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            key = (char) br.read();
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return key;
    }
```

> java.io.IOException: Stream closed    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)    at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)  at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:175)

Comment: Seems pretty clear: you are running the program without a console.

Comment: What do you mean "without a console"?

Comment: The error message says System.in is closed. This means that it's not connected to an open device or file. In other words, the program is running without a console. If you told is where and how you are running the program someone might be able to suggest a fix.

Comment: I try to run it from eclipse..

Comment: @stebetko: Are you running this from a fairly small body of code in Eclipse? If so, post that additional code.

Comment: @AndrewMartin It is a part of more complex logic. I use this to test websocket communication with tomcat server. So when message is received there is an option to choose response through console input.